# How to use git log -L /regex/ with linebreak?

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, git-log

Git documentstion https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log says that there is a command

```
git log -L <start>,<end>:<file>
```

"start" and "end" can be number, /regex/, +offset or -offset.

I am looking for commits that modify a piece of code matching the regular expression. For this I put the regular expression in "start" and offset="+1" in "end'.

But I was faced with a problem: I have a regular expression that consists of several lines. Is it possible to insert a line separator in /regex/ used in "git log -L"?

Or, is there some other way to look at the history of commits that modify a piece of code that matches a regular expression consisting of several lines?